# wp_insert_post not working for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, api, wp-insert-post

For whatever reason `wp_insert_post` doesn't work for a custom post type.

Here's the code snippet I'm using.

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_type' => 'rsp_synonym',
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $row['word'] ),
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => 2,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'open',
    'ping_status' => 'open'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "- " . $error . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Strange enough, it doesn't even return a WP_Error using the `if (is_wp_error($post_id))` conditional. But still, no posts are being added.

The custom post type named as `rsp_synonym` has been registered before using this call.

Comment: Did you try this function with user sessions.?.  Sometimes it requires strong user sessions to submit a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add the second parameter like:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, true );
```

If it still won't work, please var_dump the $post_id and paste here.

Comment: Hi, thanks! That did help a lot. As I'm using `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` in my script in order to get data from a DB different than the one WP uses, it seems that `wp_insert_post` changes its DB connection too. Weird.

Comment: @oschloebe how did you fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of wp_insert_posts, create your own "call" using $wpdb which you can then set your own database e.g.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tablename';
$wpdb->insert( 
 $table_name, 
 array(
    // data to add
 ) 
);
```

You can read more on custom tables at http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins